# iphone: delete row from sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have tried many ways to achieve this biut unable to delete row from sqlite, please help me to correct following piece of code

```
dbPath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
NSLog(@"%@", dbPath);
dbPath=[dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database"];
dbPath=[dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"OFFENDERSDB.sqlite"];

NSLog(@"database path --> %@", dbPath);

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char *sqlStatement = ("DELETE * from OFFENDERS_LIST where ID=%d ",2);

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSLog(@"offender deleted");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Comment: Pretty funny assessment above, coming from a person who developed  `NSPredicate`Editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried using:

```
sqlite3_exec(database, sqlStatement...
```

with your DELETE statement?

**ALSO.... it's DELETE FROM....   not DELETE * FROM....**

Snagged the following code from another place out on the internet for a more complete example...

```
sqlite3 *db;
int rc;

rc = sqlite3_open( "C:\\MyDatabase", &db );

if ( rc )
{
        sqlite3_close(db);
}
else //Database connection opened successfuly
{
        char *zErrMsg = 0;

        rc = sqlite3_exec( db, "DELETE FROM yourTable", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg );

        if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
        {
                sqlite3_free( zErrMsg );
        }

        sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Comment: can you give me the complete statement even that is also not working for me

Comment: Added the comment about DELETE FROM not DELETE * FROM above.   Did you fix that too?

Comment: even aftre this row is not getting deleted

Comment: Have you tried printing out the exact statement that is being processed, then cut and paste it in your favorite sqlite query browser to see if there is some issue with the table name or statement?  I use NaviCat Lite and when I'm having difficulties like this, just paste it in there to make sure there aren't DB issues at play rather than code.

Comment: yupp there is no db issue the end result == SQLITE_OK we have to sqlite3_finalize it but dont know how to do that

Comment: Did you still try it in the query browser and make sure the row deletes?  I've seen some strange stuff happen that I still don't have answers for.  Make sure the row deletes by executing the same statement in the query browser.  Once you close the DB it should finalize anything you've done.  The only reason I keep asking about the query browser is because I've had statements return SQLITE_OK but the record wasn't changed.  As it turned out there was an issue with the statement/tables structures/data types/etc. after all, and in query browser it was more obvious.

Comment: removing the * worked for me.  The sad thing is I knew this and have done it in Java a lot for my android apps.